# bootstrap vue select, how to catch input focusout event

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a select:

```
  <b-form-select
     @input="genderErrors()"
     v-model="user.gender.value"
     :options="user.gender.items"
     class="mdb-select md-form gender-class"
  ></b-form-select>
 <b-form-invalid-feedback
    v-show="user.gender.errors.length > 0"
 >{{user.gender.errors.join(' ')}}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
```

and validation for it:

```
import {validationMixin} from 'vuelidate'
import {required} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
export default {
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  name: 'App',
  validations: {
    user: {
      gender: {
        value: {
          required,
        }
      }
   },
   data: () => ({
      gender: {
        items : [
          {value:'male', text: 'Male'},
          {value: 'female', text: 'Female'},
          {value: null, text: 'Gender'}
          ],
        value: null,
        errors: []
      },
   }),
   methods{
     genderErrors(person) {
          console.log('hahah')
          this.$v.[person].gender.value.$touch();
          this.[person].gender.errors = [];
    
          if (!this.$v.[person].gender.value.$dirty) {
            return;
          }
    
          if (!this.$v.[person].gender.value.required) {
            this.[person].gender.errors.push('Gender required')

          }
  
        },
    }
}
```

in this example, it's a trigger `genderErrors` only when I select some option, but I want to trigger it also when related input is out of focus, to determine if the user clicks on input but does not select any value. Depends on the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#comp-ref-b-form-select-events) it does not support that event, but maybe there are some way of doing it???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@blur.native="onBlur($event)"`. Take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-select-native-p2udu)